YARP health checks all fail with Unauthorized
I have four active health checks on each of four clusters using YARP as a load balancer.
ProbingCompleted() in the health policy is being fired and I'm recording results for each one.  But all I ever get for the response status for all checks is Unauthorized.
All of the health checks are open (https only), they don't enforce authentication or authorization, and I can hit the same URL's in Fiddler or browser to get a 200 response from each as expected.  Each health check is a separate app from, and are on different servers, and not routed through YARP load balancing.
Does anyone have any ideas what YARP is doing differently for these health requests that would cause this?  And what I might do to correct it?
